# WARN: 'The "slidestart" event cannot be bound because Hammer.JS is not loaded and no custom loader has been specified.'

Tags: angular, unit-testing, tfs, tfsbuild

This error appears in TFS build output when running the unit tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by simply adding an import into **test.ts**

```
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
**import 'hammerjs';**

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context( './', true, /\.spec\.ts$/ );
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map( context );
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following provider fixed the issue for me:

```js
...
import { HAMMER_LOADER } from '@angular/platform-browser';

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ... ],
      imports: [ ... ],
      providers: [
        ...,
        { provide: HAMMER_LOADER, useValue: () => new Promise(() => {}) } ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```